# Too fast playback mu-law gstreamer1.0

Tags: gstreamer, mu-law

I dumped raw RTP payload in mu-law format into a file and feeded this file into gstreamer like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=interlocutor2.raw ! audio/x-mulaw, rate=8000, channels=1 ! mulawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

But it playbacks too fast. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: doublecheck `rate` in audio caps, try to set 16k or 4k

Comment: it's PCMU, so it's definetely 8k. And I cannot lower it to 4r, gstreamer crashes.

Comment: This should play directly to your audiosink without using convert and resample, which may be causing the problem. Please provide the raw file.